# Is there a Stack Exchange site for watches?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a lot of questions about (wrist) watches, but I don't see any site on Stack Exchange about watches. I found a watch Q&A on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Watches/). Quora also as [topic about watches](https://www.quora.com/topic/Watches). So I wonder if Stack Exchange has a community where questions about watches would be appropriate?

I have tried to find watch site on [Current list of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (10/15/2017), but I don't find anything about watch.

Also I try to log in to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to propose a new site, but strangely, I can't ask question there.

So pardon me if I post this question at the wrong site.

Comment: No such site, and I don't think the scope is big enough to justify whole new site just for watches. I mean, what can you ask there? What is the best watch? Identify this watch? I'm afraid this is one of the things SE simply can't have.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Fair enough :) After I think again, I think discuss in forum topic should be more appropriate.
PS: I think appropriate question maybe: what is the spec for watch X, How to prevent watch from getting slow by gravity,...

Comment: Oh, I remember what did I want to ask if there is this site: why some watch only provide date only instead of day-date. I mean what the point when see that date is 14 but don't know today is Sunday.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. If you really think such site can stand on its own, feel free to [propose a new site in Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology). :-)

Comment: There used to be an Area51 proposal for a Clockwork site, but it died due to lack of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at the moment.

I'd note though, on many sites - why did "foo" choose to do "bar" this way. There's also (from a quick glance) very few 'collector' or 'object' centeric sites - most sites are more about care and maintenance  (Take a look at [mechanics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)) or say watch questions on lifehacks or other sites, [like this](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14039/how-do-i-open-this-watch-without-special-tools/)) for ideas for seed questions.

How do I open/maintain this works better than "why did foo do bar" - since only the designer can really answer.

It does seem *potentially* viable, especially if you included the mechanical watch communities (complicated devices which need a lot of love) and smartwatch communities in your scope.

Comment: It's true :) I'll wait for it :)